# python file content sorting

Tags: python, sorting

My file content is below:

```
Dnext_0[11]
Dnext_1[0]
Dnext_0[0]
Dnext_0[128]
Dnext_0[1]
```

After sorting, I want to have:

```
Dnext_0[0]
Dnext_0[1]
Dnext_0[11]
Dnext_0[128]
Dnext_1[0]
```

I have tried this:

```
with open('testfile') as f:
    sorted_file = sorted(f)

print sorted_file
```

But it does not give me what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort the data you have specifying `key` `lambda` function that extracts the numbers after the `Dnext_` and inside the brackets using [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('Dnext_(\d+)\[(\d+)\]')
with open('input.txt') as f:
    print sorted(f, key=lambda x: map(int, pattern.search(x).groups()))
```

prints:

```
Dnext_0[0]
Dnext_0[1]
Dnext_0[11]
Dnext_0[128]
Dnext_1[0]
```

`Dnext_(\d+)\[(\d+)\]` regular expression uses capturing groups to extract the number after `Dnext_` and the number in the brackets:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('Dnext_(\d+)\[(\d+)\]')
>>> pattern.search('Dnext_0[11]').groups()
('0', '11')
```

`map(int, ... )` helps to convert the extract numbers to python integers (see [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)):

```
>>> map(int, pattern.search('Dnext_0[11]').groups())
[0, 11]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function returning a tuple containing what you want to order lines by, and use that as the key.

```
sorted(f.readlines(), key=lambda x:(int(x[6]), int(x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0])))
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps .. Result should be :
['Dnext_0[0]', 'Dnext_0[11]', 'Dnext_0[128]', 'Dnext_0[1]', 'Dnext_1[0]']

```
with open('testfile') as f:
    l=f.readline()
    a=l.split()
    b=sorted(a)

print "original data is is ",l
print "Original data with comma is ",a
print "sorted data is ",b
```

The question was changed when i posted the answer .Below answer is not perfect but may help you :

```
with open('testfile') as f:
    l=f.readlines()
    #=l.split()
    b=sorted(l)

print "original data is is ",l
#print "Original data with comma is ",a
print "sorted data is ",b
for i in b:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

default compare way is to treat the input as pure string, and it doesn't know about the integer should be treated differently than others.

Your way gets Dnext_0[128] before Dnext_0[1] is because '2' is smaller than ']'.
To get the expected result, you need to tell the sorted function how to sort, by giving it what to compare (the `key` argument), or telling it how to compare two string (the `cmp` argument). Refer to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function `sorting_criteria()` that defines how do you want to sort the lines from the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

def sorting_criteria(line):
    """Dnext_0[11] -> [0, 11]"""
    m = re.search(r'_(\d+)\[(\d+)\]\s*$', line, re.M)
    return map(int, m.groups()) if m else []

with open('testfile') as file:
    sorted_file = sorted(map(str.strip, file), key=sorting_criteria)
print '\n'.join(sorted_file)
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/x1IqdE)

```
Dnext_0[0]
Dnext_0[1]
Dnext_0[11]
Dnext_0[128]
Dnext_1[0]
```